# Useful UserScripts?

Tags: discussion, appearance

I am experimenting with some UserScripts to provide additional functionality that the StackExchange sites currently do not support.

In particular, two have proved highly useful:

- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/689/latex-rendering-delay shows how to reduce the TeX preview delay from the default 5 seconds (!).  Thanks to @Sadeq for the detective work in [Why is our LaTeX math support so different from that of MathOverflow?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485)
- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/71948 threads comments based on time and `@`-tagged names used in the comments

I would like to hear about UserScripts that others have found useful on CSTheory.

There are also some generic lists (the functionality of quite a few of these has subsequently been incorporated by the StackExchange sites):

- [What third-party tools are there for the trilogy websites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow)
- http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=stack+overflow&x=0&y=0
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=userscript

Comment: Excellent question! For those unfamiliar with UserScripts: See http://userscripts.org/about/installing (FireFox), http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/ (Opera), http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts (Chromium/Chrome/Iron), and http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/greasemonkey-alternatives-for-ie-opera-and-safari.html (Internet Explorer/Safari/Opera).

Comment: I was going to add http://stackprinter.appspot.com/ for printing questions with their answers, but the service has just been suspended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A number of userscripts can be found on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) which is our site for apps and add-ons people have written for the Stack Exchange network.

There are quite a few [scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) listed there.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange has an experimental feature called [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/feedback-request-newer-timeline-question-view).  Currently the timeline page of a question can be reached only by tweaking the URL, but there is a [user script by quack quixote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40617/a-greasemonkey-script-that-adds-timeline-links-to-all-the-questions/40623#40623) which adds a proper link.

By default, the user script does not work on any *.stackexchange.com sites.  You have to add the following line to the declaration part:

```
// @include http://*.stackexchange.com/*
```

I have been using it for a month and it has never caused a problem as far as I know, which is great.

Comment: Massively useful, thanks!

Comment: The user script on Meta Stack Overflow is gone.  I found [another user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2371/add-imeline-and-evisions-links) which seems to have a similar functionality, but I have not tried it.

Comment: This appears to be a slightly enhanced replacement.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Note that the replacement script sometimes fails to put in revisions links.  I have edited my copy to make the appropriate lines unconditional.

Answer (score 5):

[StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) produces an essential printable view of a given question id with all the answers and all the comments.

I have added TeX support for your printing/reading pleasure, [here](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=cstheory.stackexchange&printer=false&question=79) an example.
Apps details [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite), hope it helps.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for adding TeX support!  I'm glad my comment above from October has proved to be wrong...

Answer (score 5):

I hope that a user style sheet is also acceptable here.

If you are worried too much by your reputation score, the following user style sheet for Firefox may ease your feeling.  It hides your reputation score from the header of every page.

```
@-moz-document domain(stackexchange.com) {
  #topbar .reputation-score {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

To use it, put it in the file `〈PROFILE_DIRECTORY〉/chrome/userContent.css`, with `〈PROFILE_DIRECTORY〉` substituted by your [profile directory](http://support.mozilla.org/kb/Profiles) (not surprisingly).  You may have to create the `〈PROFILE_DIRECTORY〉/chrome` directory by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I somehow forgot to post the user script “[Disable enter for submitting comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments)” by Jeff Atwood of Stack Overflow Internet Services.  As the name says, this user script prevents pressing the Enter key from submitting a comment.

Because I use an [input method editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) to enter symbols such as quotation marks and mathematical symbols, I find it very difficult to write comments without this user script.  I do not think that this applies to many people, but if you are experiencing the same problem, the user script will save you a lot of time.

Comment: This script has been really useful since I started using a third-party editor for browser `textarea` fields.

Answer (score 5):

#### [bold and colorful area tags](https://stackapps.com/q/2566/5800)

I wrote a script to change the way the area tags are displayed, now they are bold and colorful.

Comment: Nice ! just installed it.

Comment: Rather useful, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another user style sheet.  The [same instruction as my previous one](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/useful-userscripts/1020#1020) applies.

If you think that the [three “share” icons are distracting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120436/would-the-new-share-buttons-benefit-from-being-grey), the following user style sheet may be useful.  This makes the three icons less pronounced.  Hovering the mouse restores the original color.

```
@-moz-document domain(stackexchange.com) {
  .gp-share {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  .fb-share, .twitter-share {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .gp-share:hover, .fb-share:hover, .twitter-share:hover, .gp-share:focus, .fb-share:focus, .twitter-share:focus, .gp-share:active, .fb-share:active, .twitter-share:active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found these tricks useful:

- Forcing that MathJax re-renders Latex math after clicking on "show N more comments": [Latex math and "show N more comments"](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/latex-math-and-show-n-more-comments/294#294)
- Show only questions with "interesting" tags: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/509/see-only-questions-with-interesting-tags/

Not sure if you can call these things UserScripts, though. They are just bookmarks that include a fragment of JavaScript code.

Comment: They seem useful too, thanks for the pointers!  My question was perhaps phrased in an overly specific way.

Comment: The user script for “show N more comments” is no longer needed.  http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/293/latex-math-and-show-n-more-comments/648#648

Answer (score 3):

[SE editor toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit)

Adds new buttons to the editor (e.g. search and replace) and automates a number of editing tasks (e.g. auto-fixing spelling errors).

Answer (score 2):

[Citation Helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1485/formatting-citations-to-the-literature-on-mathoverflow)

Adds a button for adding citations. See [this demonstration video](http://youtu.be/hrCUjtepj7E).