# Math Mode Breaks When Showing All Comments

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latex math and “show N more comments”](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/latex-math-and-show-n-more-comments)

Math mode works fine -- if slow -- for me until I click on "show more comments"; then, all renderings in this comment thread are again replaced with LaTeX code. Other comment threads on the same question as well as question and answer texts are not affected.

Please confirm this (users) resp fix this (tech admins).

Comment: Whoops. Sorry for that. Cannot delete the question because it is closed, how weird...